# iPhone static code analysis from Terminal fails to find a missing ivar release

Tags: iphone, ios4, clang

I have a script that I run in terminal that runs the scan-build code analyzer on my iPhone applications to check for issues. I just noticed quite by accident that there is at least one instance where it is not finding an IBOutlet ivar that is not being released in the dealloc method.

Here is the contents of the command I run from the Terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Developer/svn/MyCompany/iPhone/MyApplication
scan-build -analyzer-check-dead-stores -analyzer-check-llvm-conventions -analyzer-check-objc-mem -analyzer-check-objc-methodsigs -analyzer-check-objc-missing-dealloc -analyzer-check-objc-unused-ivars -analyzer-check-security-syntactic --experimental-checks -k -V -o scan-reports xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.2 clean build
```

I have updated to the very latest version of checker, so it can't be that there is a newer version of checker. Here are the pertinent parts of the .h file for my class:

```
@interface LoginWizardUsernameViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, GetUserExistsDidFinish> {

 IBOutlet UITextField *username;
 IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
```

And here are the pertinent parts of the .m file:

```
// lots o' code omitted here

@implementation LoginWizardUsernameViewController

@synthesize username;
@synthesize activityIndicatorView;

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

As you can see, there is no release of the two IBOutlet items, but even though they are listed as retained in the property definition, checker is not seeing this for some reason. The strange thing is that I can go to the .m file of other classes and comment out a release in the dealloc method, and scan-build happily alerts me at the end of the scan of the problem. I just cannot figure out what is different about this particular situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8838) in the Clang static analyzer, caused by an attempt to fix a different [issue](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2517).

Based on the [source code](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CheckObjCDealloc_8cpp_source.html), the Clang static analyzer will skip `-dealloc` checking for any class which contains *only* non-pointer ivars or `IBOutlet` ivars:

```
104   // Does the class contain any ivars that are pointers (or id<...>)?
105   // If not, skip the check entirely.
106   // NOTE: This is motivated by PR 2517:
107   //        http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2517
108 
109  bool containsPointerIvar = false;
110  
111  for (ObjCInterfaceDecl::ivar_iterator I=ID->ivar_begin(), E=ID->ivar_end();
112       I!=E; ++I) {
113 
114    ObjCIvarDecl* ID = *I;
115    QualType T = ID->getType();
116 
117    if (!T->isObjCObjectPointerType() ||
118        ID->getAttr<IBOutletAttr>() || // Skip IBOutlets.
119        ID->getAttr<IBOutletCollectionAttr>()) // Skip IBOutletCollections.
120      continue;
121 
122    containsPointerIvar = true;
123    break;
124  }
125 
126  if (!containsPointerIvar)
127    return;
```

I suspect that it will work properly if you simply add a non-IBOutlet property to your class.

Comment: Update: I have submitted a bug report for this issue. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8838

Comment: Right on the money, I added an NSString retained item in the class as a property, and it all of a sudden started complaining about the missing releases on the IBOutlets.  Thanks.